# NodeMcu Web_Server won't reload when new client connects

Tags: arduino, nodemcu

Well I become interested in NodeMcu a couple of days ago and I have tried to make a Wifi Server which can control the four Gpios connected to the Board. I was able to create the code and it works flawlessly but the problem I am facing could be the board's behaviour or what I don't know . Basically when the board is powered ON the newly connected client is able to control the gpio(s) but when it disconnects and tries to connect again it doesn't reload the page it just stucks and wont show the web page . If I reset(POWER OFF and then ON)the board then the first client is able to access the webpage.. What could be the problem if it's code related then I will post the code but first tell me that it is because I am suspecting that it's the board nature it works like this.

```
  #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
    const char* ssid = "Anshumaan";  // Enter SSID here
    const char* password = "zxcvbnm123";  //Enter Password here
// Variable to store the HTTP request
String header;
String LED1State = "off";
String LED2State = "off";
String LED3State = "off";
String LED4State = "off";
const int LED1 = D0;
const int LED2 = D1;
const int LED3 = D2;
const int LED4 = D3;
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED4, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED4, LOW);
 Serial.print("Connecting to ");
 Serial.println(ssid);
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
   Serial.print(".");
 }
// Print local IP address and start web server
 Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected-->");
  Serial.println("Copy this IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
}

void loop(){
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   
  if (client) {                             // If a new client connects,
    Serial.println("new client connected");          
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected())
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             
        Serial.write(c);                    
        header += c;
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println();
            //LED _1 and its change of state
            if (header.indexOf("GET /LED1/on") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("LED1 on");
              LED1State = "on";
              digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /LED1/off") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("LED1 off");
              LED1State = "off";
              digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
            } 
            //LED_ 2 and its change of state
            if (header.indexOf("GET /LED2/on") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("LED2 on");
              LED2State = "on";
              digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /LED2/off") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("LED2 off");
              LED2State = "off";
              digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
            } 
            //LED _3 and its change of state
            if (header.indexOf("GET /LED3/on") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("LED3 on");
              LED3State = "on";
              digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /LED3/off") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("LED3 off");
              LED3State = "off";
              digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
            } 
            //LED_4 and its change of state
            if (header.indexOf("GET /LED4/on") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("LED4 on");
              LED4State = "on";
              digitalWrite(LED4, HIGH);
            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /LED4/off") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("LED4 off");
              LED4State = "off";
              digitalWrite(LED4, LOW);
            } 

            // Display the HTML web page
            //displaying what is above the name below
            client.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html>");
            client.println("<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">");
            client.println("<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:,\">");
            client.println("<style>html { font-family: Cairo; display: inline; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center; background-color: #ccffb3;}");
            client.println(".button { background-color: #006699; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 40px;");
            client.println("text-decoration: none; font-size: 35px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer;}");
            client.println(".button2 {background-color: #555555;}</style></head>");

            //to print the name
            client.println("<svg width=\"300\" height=\"80\"><text fill=\"#00bfbf\" font-family=\"serif\" font-size=\"24\" id=\"svg_1\" stroke=\"#000000\" text-anchor=\"middle\" transform=\"matrix(1.35388 0 0 1.42308 -6.66283 -8.67308)\" x=\"100.5\" xml:space=\"preserve\" y=\"41.5\">Anshumaan Kumar</text></svg>");

            // Web Page Heading
            client.println("<body><h1>Welcome Webserver version 1.0</h1>");
            client.println("<p>Output_1 is: " + LED1State + "</p>");
            // If the LED1State is off, it displays the ON button       
            if (LED1State=="off") {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/LED1/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button></a></p>");
             // client.println("<svg width=\"500\" height=\"300\"><ellipse cx=\"258.5\" cy=\"125.5\" fill=\"#ffffff\" rx=\"47\" ry=\"52\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\"/><rect fill=\"#cccccc\" height=\"40\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\" transform=\"rotate(-0.485546 261 187.5)\" width=\"39\" x=\"241.5\" y=\"167.5\"/></svg>");

            } else {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/LED1/off\"><button class=\"button button2\">OFF</button></a></p>");
              //client.println("<svg width=\"500\" height=\"300\"><ellipse cx=\"258.5\" cy=\"125.5\" fill=\"#ff7f00\" rx=\"47\" ry=\"52\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\"/><rect fill=\"#cccccc\" height=\"40\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\" transform=\"rotate(-0.485546 261 187.5)\" width=\"39\" x=\"241.5\" y=\"167.5\"/></svg>");

            }     
             client.println("<p>Output_2 is: " + LED2State + "</p>");
            // If the LED1State is off, it displays the ON button       
            if (LED2State=="off") {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/LED2/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button></a></p>");
             // client.println("<svg width=\"500\" height=\"300\"><ellipse cx=\"258.5\" cy=\"125.5\" fill=\"#ffffff\" rx=\"47\" ry=\"52\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\"/><rect fill=\"#cccccc\" height=\"40\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\" transform=\"rotate(-0.485546 261 187.5)\" width=\"39\" x=\"241.5\" y=\"167.5\"/></svg>");

            } else {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/LED2/off\"><button class=\"button button2\">OFF</button></a></p>");
              //client.println("<svg width=\"500\" height=\"300\"><ellipse cx=\"258.5\" cy=\"125.5\" fill=\"#ff7f00\" rx=\"47\" ry=\"52\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\"/><rect fill=\"#cccccc\" height=\"40\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\" transform=\"rotate(-0.485546 261 187.5)\" width=\"39\" x=\"241.5\" y=\"167.5\"/></svg>");

            }     
             client.println("<p>Output_3 is: " + LED3State + "</p>");
            // If the LED1State is off, it displays the ON button       
            if (LED3State=="off") {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/LED3/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button></a></p>");
             // client.println("<svg width=\"500\" height=\"300\"><ellipse cx=\"258.5\" cy=\"125.5\" fill=\"#ffffff\" rx=\"47\" ry=\"52\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\"/><rect fill=\"#cccccc\" height=\"40\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\" transform=\"rotate(-0.485546 261 187.5)\" width=\"39\" x=\"241.5\" y=\"167.5\"/></svg>");

            } else {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/LED3/off\"><button class=\"button button2\">OFF</button></a></p>");
              //client.println("<svg width=\"500\" height=\"300\"><ellipse cx=\"258.5\" cy=\"125.5\" fill=\"#ff7f00\" rx=\"47\" ry=\"52\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\"/><rect fill=\"#cccccc\" height=\"40\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\" transform=\"rotate(-0.485546 261 187.5)\" width=\"39\" x=\"241.5\" y=\"167.5\"/></svg>");

            }     
             client.println("<p>Output_4 is: " + LED4State + "</p>");
            // If the LED1State is off, it displays the ON button       
            if (LED4State=="off") {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/LED4/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button></a></p>");
             // client.println("<svg width=\"500\" height=\"300\"><ellipse cx=\"258.5\" cy=\"125.5\" fill=\"#ffffff\" rx=\"47\" ry=\"52\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\"/><rect fill=\"#cccccc\" height=\"40\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\" transform=\"rotate(-0.485546 261 187.5)\" width=\"39\" x=\"241.5\" y=\"167.5\"/></svg>");

            } else {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/LED4/off\"><button class=\"button button2\">OFF</button></a></p>");
              //client.println("<svg width=\"500\" height=\"300\"><ellipse cx=\"258.5\" cy=\"125.5\" fill=\"#ff7f00\" rx=\"47\" ry=\"52\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\"/><rect fill=\"#cccccc\" height=\"40\" stroke=\"#ffffaa\" stroke-width=\"5\" transform=\"rotate(-0.485546 261 187.5)\" width=\"39\" x=\"241.5\" y=\"167.5\"/></svg>");

            }     
            client.println("</body></html>");
            client.println();
            break;
          } else { 
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  
          currentLine += c;      
        }
      }
    }
    header = "";
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected");
    Serial.println("");
  }
```

what I am doing wrong.

Comment: OK. If I post that can you examine that where I am making a mistake

Comment: the problem in your sketch is that it doesn't read the entire request so it sends the response before the browser finished to send the request. Browsers don't like it and abort the connection.

Comment: Oh thanks for the help I am working on it